# Android TabHost layout location

Tags: android, xml, android-tabhost

I have a problem placing a TabHost, as you can see in the image, the TabHost is not well placed in the screen (bottom area is below limits). I want the tabs in the middle of the screen, not on the top, the top part is occupied by a chart, this part is deliberate (Why is occupying more space in the bottom?)

[image]

The xml code is like this:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2.0"
    android:padding="5dp">

CHART IS HERE OCCUPYING A PART OF THE SCREEN

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

After all, the problem is that although the tab content is shown, due to the hide TabHost part, the scroll doesn't allows you to see the entire content.

Comment: Is the TabHost in a LinearLayout?

Comment: No, is the root. But if I wrap it into a LinearLayout it has the same behavior.

Comment: So how did you add the view on top?

Comment: TabWidget and FrameLayout are into a LinearLayout. And this LinearLayout is inside the TabHost. TabHost is the root. The result is  the attached image. If I wrap everything into another LienarLayout nothing changes.

Comment: Don’t wrap everything into another LienarLayout, make a LienarLayout as the root, and add the first view and then the TabHost,

Comment: Thanks, you saved me! I added TabHost as another view inside a root LienarLayout and then TabWidget and FrameLayout inside another LienarLayout just after the TabHost and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

This code seems to works fine when added as a view inside a LinearLayout

```
<TabHost 
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:padding="5dp">
  <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```